# Is there any arrival lounge at Rome Fiumicino airport terminal 3?

Tags: rome, lounges, fco

I will be arriving very early, around 2AM at terminal 3. My hostel check-in time is 2PM. So, I'll leave the airport at around 7AM in the morning.

I want to know if there are any arrival lounges available at the airport where I can recharge myself?

Comment: Where does your flight arrive from? It's possibly relevant because of how large T3 is and a separate non-Schengen area.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well I'll be coming in from India, with a layover in Abu Dhabi.

Comment: All the lounges I can find are in departures (and don't open until after 6 am anyway) but perhaps someone else knows something I do not.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the list of lounges present at the Fiumicino Airport on the [Aeroporti di Roma](https://www.adr.it/web/aeroporti-di-roma-en/vip-lounge) website

The only lounge not on the departures area is [The HelloSky Arrival Lounge & Air Rooms](https://www.adr.it/web/aeroporti-di-roma-en/hellosky)

Opening hours - daily from 6am until 11pm.